# how to prepare for a face to face serial interviews

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, hiring

Is there any links, guides, cheat sheets to help prepare for a face to face serial interviews at a company site? Please share

Comment: Can you explain what "serial" refers to?

Comment: I interviewed with Cap'n Crunch last week, was that a cereal interview?

Answer (score 2):

If you are the right person for the job, why need a cheat sheet ? If you are trying to sneak in under false pretenses, please DON'T. It is an invitation for disaster. You may get dismissed and it goes on your record. Whenever a future employer asks for references, it will come up.

What you are referring to as the serial interviews, is something like being invited to the employer's site and having one meeting after another with people from different department of the same company. It usually happens with large corporations with multiple divisions, where your background may be utilized. These interviews are usually for finding out who can have the most benefits from what you offer. If you are invited to one of these, it means, you have impressed the initial screener. Now it is the go time and show that you are really who you said you are. And for that, you can have no cheat sheet, as they will throw fictitious problems at you at the interviews and see how you think when it comes to resolving those. If you have an analytical mind, you have nothing to worry.